# Accessing sitecore sublayout properties in a usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

---

I have a sublayout that has an asp.net wizard.  For each wizard step I want to be able to call a asp.net user control to display the content.

I created a template that has some fields and I want to be able to access these fields in my user controls.

In my user control I tried getting my sublayout by doing the following:

```
Sublayout thisSublayout = (Parent as Sublayout);
```

But this returns a null.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Below is the code i'm using:

**MySublayout.ascx**

All i'm doing here is dropping my user control on the page.  The template that I associate with this sublayout has a "My Template Field".

```
<uctrl:MyNestedUC ID="ucMyUserControl" runat="server" >

</uctrl:MyNestedUC>
```

**MyNestedUC.ascx**

This page just has a scText attribute on it:

```
<sc:Text runat="server" ID="scMyTemplateField" Field="My Template Field" />
```

**MyNestedUC.ascx.cs**

In my pageload method this is all i'm doing:

```
scMyTemplateField.Item = Sitecore.Context.Item;
```

The scMyTemplateField is null so trying to access scMyTemplateField.Item returns a null reference error.

The directives at the top of each page look like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="My Sublayout.ascx.cs" Inherits="Sublayouts.content.My_Sublayout" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyNestedUC.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls.MyNestedUC" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've misunderstood what you're saying, but if you're referencing the sublayout from a user control that is inside another user control, then it would probably be the "grand parent" that you need to cast:

```
Sublayout thisSublayout = (Parent.Parent as Sublayout);
```

Comment: Clutching at straws, but have you tried setting the `Datasource` property with the context item ID  rather than using `Item`?

Comment: yup I tried this as well....same issue.  For some reason it doesn't know what my scMyTextField is.  But I mean its a field renderer control that's in my .ascx so I don't see why it would be null.  Whats the difference if I put the scText control or another asp.net control.  Do I need to initialize it somewhere?  I'm confused :(

Comment: this is what is in my designer.cs file: protected global::Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Text scMyTextField;

Comment: Check the directive at the top of your user control and compare it with other controls that are working. you may find that it is using incorrect attributes.

Comment: I haven't been able to get a user control working with my sublayout so I don't have any attributes to compare.

Comment: Ok then can you append something extra to your question - the directive from the top of both the user control and the sublayout files (It should be the first line the file, beginning with `<%@ Control`

Answer (score 0):

As @TwentyGotoTen mentions, you probably are missing a level for accessing the Sublayout.

That being said, if the fields are on the item, you won't need to access the Sublayout. You can directly query the Sitecore.Context.Item from your user control.

If the fields are on a Sublayout parameter template, or are on a component datasource attached to your sublayout, you will have to crawl up the parent tree to find the parent that is a Sublayout.

Alternatively, and this is my preferred approach, when instantiating user controls on a Sublayout I pass any necessary data to the user control on public properties. This allows for the user control to be used in any situation, so long as it is initialized correctly.

For example, you might add a public property on the user control named 'DataSource' with type 'Item', and then have your sublayout specify the property value as it is initialized.

Comment: so I tried it and it doesn't work out for me.  What i'm doing is I have a sublayout that uses a template.  This template has a text field called MyTextField.  All the sublayout is doing is calling a usercontrol which contains a sc:Text rendering that points to MyTextField.  In my pageload of the usercontrol I set the Item of scMyTextField.Item = Sitecore.Context.Item.  I get a null reference error on scMyTextField.  Any ideas why?

Comment: In your debugger, what object is Sitecore.Context.Item? Is it the item you are looking for?

Comment: Yup the Sitecore.Context.Item is exactly what i'm looking for.  But i'm not sure why my scText field is returning null.  I'm stumped.  Since my usercontrol is a basic asp.net web usercontrol maybe it doesn't recognize the sitecore scText?

Comment: The sc:Text is looking for a datasource (which is sometimes the same item as the Context.Item). As you already know, the control is unable to detect the sublayout and therefore it can't get a datasource. I suggest you post your code so it's clearer for us to see what's going on.

Comment: @TwentyGotoTen I've updated my original question with the code.  Not much to my code just a few lines.

Comment: @TwentyGotoTen I get the same issue when I use Parent.Parent

Comment: I'm assuming this code can compile, so the actual scMyTemplateField control must actually be defined in the designer file. However, it seems that at the point in time that you try to affect the control (during your pageload) there is no control defined yet. Try removing the line and letting the code run. By default, Sitecore will try to bind to Sitecore.Context.Item if the Item property is not defined. f you do that, does that resolve your issue?

Comment: @JayS That doesn't resolve my issue.  Nothing displays on the screen.

Comment: But you are no longer receiving a null reference error? In your debugger, does the field on the item (Sitecore.Context.Item) actually have a value?

Comment: @JayS yes Sitecore.Context.Item has a value

Answer (score 0):

You can statically bind sublayout like given below -

sc:Sublayout ID="slFooterUtilityNav" Path="~/Presentation/Sublayouts/Controls/Shared/FooterUtilityNav.ascx" runat="server" />

I think, it will work for you.